# Kendo ComboBox change dataSource to json object

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a kendo combobox created using an MVC wrapper like so:

```
@Html.Kendo.ComboBox().Name("Well");
```

I want to update the data manually using a json array stored in javascript (not from an ajax query) - I came across this code which almost works except that I get [object Object] 3 times in the ComboBox instead of the 'text' value from the json array:

```
$("#Well").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.data([{text: "i1", value: "1"}, {text: "i2", value: "2"}, {text: "i3", value: "3"}]);
$("#Well").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.query();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no default for the text/value fields so adding:

```
@Html.Kendo.ComboBox().DataTextField("text").DataValueField("value").Name("Well");
```

fixes the issue.

Comment: Actually there is: `""`. If you define the data as an array of `strings`, it should work. But of course, that does not solve the case when someone needs different values for `text` and `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Following helped me to solve the problem of dynamically updating the kendo combobox datasource,

```
var combobox = $("#selector").data("kendoComboBox"); 
if(combobox){
    combobox.destroy();
    combobox.dataSource.data(NewDatasourceObject);
    combobox.refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#Well").kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: "Select...",
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            filter: "contains",
            autoBind: true,
            dataSource: {
                //type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: { url: "../your_json_url" }
                }
            }
        });
```